# C# loading a user control from a dll in mvvm

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I have a WPF app, say MyList, that has a view `MyChecklist.xaml`.

On click of a button I need to load user control from a DLL, say `MyUserControl.dll` (added as reference to MyList project) and access the controls in that user control. On click of a button on the user control I need to close `MyChecklist.xaml`.

I have included `MyUserControl` as a data template in the `MyChecklist.xaml` and set the data type to `MyUserControlViewModel` in the dictionary of `MyChecklist.xaml`. In the `MyChecklist.xaml` I have placed the user control as a content control and set the binding for viewmodel as a property in the `MyChecklistViewModel`.

I have 2 issues in this case:

1. During run time the DLL gets loaded and the user control's viewmodel is being hit. But I don't get the user control displayed. Instead I get the name of the usercontrol viewmodel in place.
2. Exception from the user control is not being thrown to `MyChecklist` exception handling mechanism

Please let me know your thoughts in tackling this. Just to mention I have used MVVM Pattern. So would be happy if anyone could help with this pattern

Comment: Sounds like there's something wrong with your DataTemplate declaration, try posting the code here. The control isn't being created in the first place which is responsible for both issues you're seeing.

Comment: Thanks. I spotted the mistake. I had given data context in both user control and the calling module. so it was getting resolved. Now i have changed it in such a way that only my calling module provides the data context.